# jQuery: incorrect background value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a simple script with jQuery, but absolutely don't understand why it's not work correctly.

```
$('#color').change(function () {
  selected = $('#color option[value=' + $(this).val() + ']');
  alert($(selected).css('background-color'));
});
```

HTML:

```
<form>
  <select id="color">
    <option value="4" style="background-color:#ff887c;">4</option>
    <option value="6" style="background-color:#ffb878;">6</option>
    <option value="7" style="background-color:#46d6db;">7</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Code on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pfe2utmq/5/)

Regardless of the option which been chosen, I'm get the same result: `rgb(51, 153, 255)`

**UPD**: unfortunately it seems like a Firefox bug

Comment: The jsFiddle seems to work fine.

Comment: it is working in my chrome

Comment: Works for me as well. Side note: you could simplify this a bit with the `:selected` selector and you don't have to pass the result of jQuery DOM lookup to jQuery again (as it is already a jQuery object) https://jsfiddle.net/pfe2utmq/6/

Comment: Weird, it doesn't work in Firefox.

Comment: @AlfonsoGarnett Yep, unfortunately it seems like a Firefox bug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this doesn't work in Firefox (Chrome is fine), seems as though there is a bug in jQuery with Firefox (likely a caching issue). Switching to native works though!

```
$(function () {
    $('#color').change(function () {
        selected = $(this).find(':selected');
        alert(selected.get(0).style.backgroundColor);
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pfe2utmq/7/

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind getting the hex color back instead of the RGB value here is some code that is working in both Chrome and Firefox. Essentially I am pulling the whole style attribute, trimming off the semi-colon at the end and manually removing the "background-color:" portion of the inline style. Not the most ideal I agree, but in a pinch it will get you the value you want.

Also, if you need to have the option of having more than one inline style in the future, you could get the index of the "#" and take the next six characters after that to get the full hex color regardless of how many other styles are in that same style attribute.

```
$(function () {
    $('#color').change(function () {
        selected = $('#color option[value=' + $(this).val() + ']');
        value = $(selected).attr('style');
        alert(value.substring(0, value.length - 1).replace('background-color:', ''));
    });
});
```